# C++ Class Conversion Operator

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-keyword

I have two classes, a Matrix, and then a Diagonal Matrix that inherits from the Matrix class.

Obviously, converting from Diagonal to Matrix is easy, but converting back requires a conversion.

```
class Diagonal : public Matrix<T>
{  
  operator Matrix<T>() const;
};
```

Exists in my code, which I thought *should* convert. In main, I have:

```
  Matrix<float> theMatrix(size,size);
  Diagonal<float> theDiag(size,size);
  theDiag = theMatrix;
```

Everything runs fine except the conversion, which tells me:

```
 no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Matrix<float>’ to ‘const Diagonal<float>&’
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
class Diagonal : public Matrix<T>
{  
  operator Matrix<T>() const;
};
```

defines a conversion from `Diagonal<T>` to `Matrix<T>`, whereas your assignment expects a conversion from `Matrix<T>` to `Diagonal<T>`.

Did you mean to write this instead?

```
class Matrix<T>
{  
  operator Diagonal<T>() const;
};
```

Now even if this works* (which I doubt, since it will cause a cyclic dependency), I'm not sure if it makes sense from a semantic perspective.  *Not every matrix is a diagonal matrix*, so converting from a matrix into a diagonal matrix cannot preserve all data.  Using implicit conversions for this situation is a bad idea from a design perspective.

*An alternative would be to define `operator=(const Matrix<T>&)` for `Diagonal<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, I totally was thinking backwards. The operator= is a good idea too.